# How to version a method on WCF?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest

I don't know if "version" is the correct word here, but I couldn't think of anything else, so here is what I want:

I have an operation contract, or web method, however you want to call it that returns a list of companies.

```
List<Company> GetCompany();
```

However this information is barely going to change overtime. So I would like to have something like this.

```
[Version="1.0"]
List<Company> GetCompany()
```

So the customer or web service consumer don't call the method unless the version change.

They(the ones that are going to use the web service) said this can by done by sending data on the Headers, but I can't find any online reference that says that I can read headers before completing the request, so I would like opinions on what's the best way to do this.

Notes: My web service is a RESTFUL WCF Webservice, this will be consumed or used from an android application.

Comment: you are looking for `Attributes`

Comment: here is a link..also if it doesn't help do a google search on `Custom Attributes` http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2933/Attributes-in-C

Comment: You mean you want the client to cache the result they get the first time until the version changes?

Comment: How will the service announce to the client when you somewhere in the future apply a `[Version="1.1"]` attribute, so the client calls the service again? Caching and cache invalidation isn't trivial, is there any reason why you want to do this?

Comment: Yes jessica. 

They will only read the version, and only update the companies if version is different.